# Using javascript, is there any way to remove characters from inside an element while leaving the other objects inside that div untouched?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that contains text and an anchor tag.

```
<div class="header">
    some text here
    <a class="button"></a>
    more text
</div>
```

I'd like to remove the characters "more text" from inside the div, but I can't just replace the html of the header div because there's javascript that's already been attached to the button that I can't reattach if I were to replace the contents of the div entirely. Is there any way I could just strip out specific words or characters but leave the rest of the elements untouched?

Thanks!

Edit: using jQuery is an acceptable option.

Comment: Solution  in duplicate will remove event handlers, try `$('.header').contents().last().remove()`  http://jsfiddle.net/rh9e36gw/

Comment: Would have been nice if they'd actually read my question before marking it as a duplicate, since the duplicate actually breaks what i'm trying to do and I very specifically said so in my question.

That being said, @charlietfl your solution worked great. Didn't know .contents() was a thing, does that just return a set of objects, groups of text being one of those objects?

Comment: Yes...include text nodes